# Check if EditText's content is settings

Tags: android, if-statement, button, android-edittext, onclicklistener

If the user clicks the "go" button, the application should check if the EditText's value is "Settings" or not? How can I do this?

Something like this:

```
Button buttn1;
EditText Text1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    buttn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button111);
    Text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text111);


    buttn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Text1 == "Settings") {
                //CODE
            }else {
                //CODE
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
if (Text1.getText().toString().equals("Settings")) {
                //CODE
            }else {
                //CODE
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of an EditText field like this: `Text1.getText().toString()` and you can check String equality using `.equals()`.

So combined, this would be `Text1.getText().toString().equals("Settings")`